# MOSS 2007 and usage tracking

Tags: 2007, site-usage

Is there any way to retrieve the usage tracking info from a remote MOSS 2007 server (i.e. nothing running on the remote server) via the object model on another domain? I'm thinking that the only way to fetch this info is to connect to an OOTB web service on the remote box, but I don't think that exists in MOSS 2007. Any ideas? I've heard of using one of the DLL files with query strings for this but I'm not sure if that would suit my needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In 2007 Usage analysis is not configured by default, but when configured logs are usually stored in the %programfiles%\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\logs.

There was an utility we've used at that time by Stephan Gobner, that could remotely read logs and pop-up notifications, find it here http://www.keirgordon.com/post/SharePoint-Log-Viewer-(ULS-Viewer).aspx

Now, on the same note, you could any tool to read from that folder and parse files, as the current ULS viewer (in SP2010) or use the Log Parser v2.2 (see here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24659) -very powerful tool

Or use a FileSystemWatcher application based that could ship your data.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Comment: Thank you for the response, Marius. Are any of these solutions feasible from one box to another (excluding 3rd party tools)? Meaning I don't have rights to install anything on the target box (also it's on a different domain). It's MOSS 2007 so the client-object model is not available. I expect not, but I just thought I'd throw the question out there.

Comment: No, the 12 folder is on the SharePoint server. Unless you can make the logs folder a network share?

Comment: I have no remote access to the file system on the remote box in question.

Comment: David, the tool actually needs no installation on the Server box, but you could share that physical location and it shall load the files!

Comment: Again, Mr. Marius, I have no access to the target's file system. It's not even located on-site (it's a .mil server). I'm dealing with MOSS 2007 so if there isn't a web service for this type of query, which is what I suspect, I'm up the creek on this one. I just needed to hear it from someone else. Thanks for your reply.